# TypeError: DOM.addEventListener(...) is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, jquery-events

I want to remove all products in my card without page refresh. I created and eventlistener, it fires when form submited. But it's now working I expecte, gives me that error.

```
const deleteCartItems = document.getElementById('deleteAllProduct');

deleteCartItems.addEventListener('submit',deleteAllCartItem)

function deleteAllCartItem(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: "/cart/delete-products",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(){
            Flash.success("Products successfully deleted");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Does it really say `DOM.addEventListener(…)`? That error isn’t possible with the code you’ve shown. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Xufox due to ";" I guess, it working right now :?

Comment: If it was due to a `;`, then you definitely failed to accurately demonstrate the problem with your code example. Next time, verify that your reduced example actually exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Well, actually I dont.. https://imgur.com/a/71LRG